# Setting up a secure mail server?

Tags: server, 14.04, security, email, mail-server

I am looking all over for a guide to setting up a secure mail server to be used with PHP and Apache. Can someone point me to a guide to do just that. I would like to have my own email (myownemail@myowndomain.com) I have setup Apache and all the other web server stuff on my Ubuntu web server hosted with amazon web services.

My next step is to setup a mail server.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this series of tutorials to be very useful:

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/how-to-run-your-own-e-mail-server-with-your-own-domain-part-1/2/

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-2-arming-your-server-with-postfix-dovecot/

http://arstechnica.com/business/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-3-fortifying-your-box-against-spammers/